# Why Is it giving me "Must declare the Scalar variable "@jobnumber" "

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, dynamic

```
    DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(8000)
    ,@jobNumber VARCHAR(25)
    ,@DBName VARCHAR(30)

    SET @jobNumber = '417133'

    DROP TABLE #Actual

    CREATE TABLE #Actual (
    jobnumber INT
    ,firstNameCounts VARCHAR(25)
    ,lastNameCounts VARCHAR(25)
    ,address1Counts VARCHAR(25)
    ,address2Counts VARCHAR(25)
    ,cityCounts VARCHAR(25)
    ,stateCounts VARCHAR(25)
    ,zipCounts VARCHAR(25)
    ,inHomeDateCounts VARCHAR(25)
    )

    SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO #actual (jobnumber,firstNameCounts,lastNameCounts , 
   address1Counts, address2Counts, cityCounts, stateCounts, zipCounts, 
   inHomeDateCounts) '
   SET @sql = @sql + ' Select s.jobnumber, count(s.firstName) AS 
   [firstNameCounts], Count (s.lastName) AS [lastNameCounts], Count (s.Address1) 
   As [address1Counts], Count (s.address2)-Count (address2) AS '
   SET @sql = @sql + ' [address2Counts], Count (s.City) AS [cityCounts], Count 
   (s.State) AS [stateCounts], Count (s.Zip) AS [zipCounts], Count 
   (jb.inHomeDate) AS [inHomeDateCounts] '
   SET @sql = @sql + ' From [s-portaldb1].[tdis_417133) + ].[dbo].
   [tblStandardFinal] s '
   SET @sql = @sql + ' INNER JOIN [s-printstream].[tdSchedule2].[dbo].
   [tblJobTicketActions] jb '
   SET @sql = @sql + ' ON jb.psFlagJobNumber = s.jobNumber '
   *SET @sql = @sql + ' where jobNumber = @jobNumber '* Getting error here 
   SET @sql = @sql + ' group by jobNumber '

   PRINT @SQL

   EXEC (@sql)

   SELECT *
   FROM #Actual
```

I am getting this

Error: Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 1
Must declare the scalar variable "@jobNumber". I have declared the value and not sure what the reason could be.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are executing SQL with `exec()` and have not provided a declaration for that variable inside the executed sql. `@sql` will be executed in its own context, and will not be able to access the variable of the same name that you have declared outside of the executed sql.

You could instead use `sp_executesql` which allows for parameter declaration and passing of parameters.

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max); /* nvarchar() instead of varchar() */
... 

exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@JobNumber Varchar(25)', @JobNumber;
```

dynamic sql reference:

- [The curse and blessings of dynamic SQL - Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)
- [**`sp_executesql`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql)

Comment: This solved the problem for me.. I appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 0):

You are running dynamic SQL - it runs in its own context and **doesn't have access** to the declared variables you have.

Either construct the dynamic SQL with the value being passed in (in the SQL string you later execute), or figure out how to do this without dynamic SQL (I don't see a reason for building the string and the `EXEC`uting it).

All that string concatenation seems completely superfluous.

So instead of this:

```
SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO #actual (jobnumber,firstNameCounts,lastNameCounts , 
address1Counts, address2Counts, cityCounts, stateCounts, zipCounts, 
inHomeDateCounts) '
SET @sql = @sql + ' Select s.jobnumber, count(s.firstName) AS 
[firstNameCounts], Count (s.lastName) AS [lastNameCounts], Count (s.Address1) 
As [address1Counts], Count (s.address2)-Count (address2) AS '
SET @sql = @sql + ' [address2Counts], Count (s.City) AS [cityCounts], Count 
(s.State) AS [stateCounts], Count (s.Zip) AS [zipCounts], Count 
(jb.inHomeDate) AS [inHomeDateCounts] '
SET @sql = @sql + ' From [s-portaldb1].[tdis_417133) + ].[dbo].
[tblStandardFinal] s '
SET @sql = @sql + ' INNER JOIN [s-printstream].[tdSchedule2].[dbo].
[tblJobTicketActions] jb '
SET @sql = @sql + ' ON jb.psFlagJobNumber = s.jobNumber '
SET @sql = @sql + ' where jobNumber = @jobNumber '
SET @sql = @sql + ' group by jobNumber '

PRINT @SQL

EXEC (@sql)
```

You should just have:

```
INSERT INTO #actual (jobnumber,firstNameCounts,lastNameCounts , 
address1Counts, address2Counts, cityCounts, stateCounts, zipCounts, 
inHomeDateCounts) 
Select s.jobnumber, count(s.firstName) AS 
[firstNameCounts], Count (s.lastName) AS [lastNameCounts], Count (s.Address1) 
As [address1Counts], Count (s.address2)-Count (address2) AS 
 [address2Counts], Count (s.City) AS [cityCounts], Count 
(s.State) AS [stateCounts], Count (s.Zip) AS [zipCounts], Count 
(jb.inHomeDate) AS [inHomeDateCounts] 
From [s-portaldb1].[tdis_417133) + ].[dbo].
[tblStandardFinal] s 
  INNER JOIN [s-printstream].[tdSchedule2].[dbo].[tblJobTicketActions] jb 
   ON jb.psFlagJobNumber = s.jobNumber 
where jobNumber = @jobNumber 
group by jobNumber
```

Comment: I chose dyanmic cuz i wanted to pass the Server/DB as dynamic.

if i can turn this into dynamic Server/DB [s-portaldb1].[tdis_417133) + ]